# Windows Storage Space Unhealthy and Detached

Tags: storage-spaces

I use Windows 11 Pro with a 3 way mirror storage space made of 5 physical disks (=2 redundant drives out of 5).
The storage pool is healthy (HealthStatus : Healthy)
All 5 physical disks are healthy (HealthStatus : Healthy)
But the storage space is not.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-VirtualDisk -friendlyname "Storage Space 3W5" | fl *
Usage                             : Data
NameFormat                        :
OperationalStatus                 : Detached
HealthStatus                      : Unhealthy
ProvisioningType                  : Thin
AllocationUnitSize                : 268435456
MediaType                         : Unspecified
ParityLayout                      :
Access                            : Read/Write
UniqueIdFormat                    : Vendor Specific
DetachedReason                    : Majority Disks Unhealthy
```

I checked this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-states
It says that "If you're not using Storage Spaces Direct, next repair the virtual disk using the Repair-VirtualDisk cmdlet." This cmdlet does not work for me. Just starts and immediately stops.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> get-storagejob
Name                       IsBackgroundTask ElapsedTime JobState PercentComplete BytesProcessed BytesTotal
----                       ---------------- ----------- -------- --------------- -------------- ----------
Storage Space 3W5-Repair   False            00:00:00    Completed 100                        0 B        0 B
```

It says also "If more disks failed than you have copies of your data and the virtual disk wasn't repaired in-between failures, all data on the virtual disk is permanently lost. In this unfortunate case, delete the virtual disk, create a new virtual disk, and then restore from a backup." Well, trying to workaround this...

I know what caused the issue. Some tinkering (dust cleaning) in my home server case left some sata cables poorly connected. So during 3 days the storage pool experienced i/o errors. But the drives are good, and I guess that all the data prior to these 3 days is good as well, and duplicated on several disks thanks to the mirroring.

But I can't get the storage space back online.
Connect-VirtualDisk is not working
Repair-VirtualDisk is not working
New-VirtualDiskSnapshot is not working
New-VirtualDiskClone is not working
Add-PhysicalDisk to the VirtualDisk is not working
Add-PhysicalDisk to the StoragePool is working OK, but does not help the virtual disk to recover, or balance, or anything. Fun fact: after adding new disks to the pool, I can't remove them because "remove-physicaldisk : The storage pool could not complete the operation because the health or operational status of one or more virtual disks in it does not permit it."

I used to use ZFS on Linux before I moved to MSFT Storage Spaces.
With ZFS, you can force a unhealthy pool to be recognized as healthy to bring it back online, and then if you're lucky you can recover some data, run scrubbing, repair, etc. I wish I could do just that: force the status of my storage space to Healthy so that I can bring it back online and at least access the data prior to the i/o errors, especially when I know the drives are not faulty (says SMART test, says ReliabilityCounter)

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-StoragePool -friendlyname "Storage Pool 3W5" | Get-PhysicalDisk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter
Number Temperature ReadErrorsUncorrected Wear PowerOnHours
------ ----------- --------------------- ---- ------------
4                  0                     0    57
6                  0                     0    63804
3                  0                     0    73344
5                  0                     0    73366
1                  0                     0    73366
7                  0                     0    67422
2                  0                     0    18745
```

Any help appreciated...
(doing ReclaiMe scan at the moment, but hoping for a solution within Windows Storage Management commands)

[(posted on microsoft.com as well)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unhealthy-and-detached-storage-space/a2d2107c-ea17-410d-94b9-91bfdd62d48d)

Comment: I think you're looking for [`Repair-SpacesConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storagespaces/repair-spacesconfiguration?view=winserver2012r2-ps) so try that and see what happens. See [StorageSpaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storagespaces/?view=winserver2012r2-ps) for more related cmdlets. Repair the storage space then once repaired, run the other `Get-VirtualDisk` cmdlets to see VD across the pool. If you suspect the pool is corrupt, that may help. Otherwise, rebuilt, then restore data from backups. Test your configuration redundancy.

Comment: @Vomit Sorry for the late reply after being away from the computer for a few weeks...
Not so sure of myself here, but I believe Repair-SpacesConfiguration cmdlet as well as StorageSpaces module are not available for Windows 11. Apparently, there is only a "all-in-one" [Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) module.

`PS C:\windows\system32> Repair-SpacesConfiguration Repair-SpacesConfiguration : The term 'Repair-SpacesConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`